# Change GRUB active - Cambiar GRUB activo

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

On a UEFI-GPT system I have installed Windows 10, KDE Neon 5.18, Ubuntu 20.04 and Kubuntu 20.04. Of course, the Grub that predominates is that of the latest installed Linux distribution. My question is how it is done to be able to choose the Grub that manages the boot, regardless of what the last distribution installed was. For example: being able to use the KDE neon 5.18 Grub even if the last distribution you have installed is Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you.

Comment: It varies by machine, but most Linux distros will 'broadcast' their bootloaders as a separate entry to the BIOS, so there may be more than one boot option to look into.